# Complex objects mapping and Nested mappings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper, dto

ok I am having a very hard time converting from a model to a dto model and vice versa
the model is valid but when trying to map "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll"

here are the Model classes

```
public class Category
    {
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }


public class Post
    {
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        public string PostMessage { get; set; }

        public string PostImage { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public Guid Category_Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category_Id")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }

    }

 public class Tag
    {
        public Guid TagId { get; set; }

        public string TagName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

and here are my DTO's

```
public class TagDto
    {
        public Guid TagId { get; set; }

        public string TagName { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<PostDto> Posts { get; set; }
    }

 public class PostDto
    {
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }


        public string PostTitle { get; set; }


        public string PostMessage { get; set; }

        public string PostImage { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TagDto> Tags { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid Category_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual CategoryDto Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is what i've been trying using the automapper to map between entities

```
public static Tag Tag_ToModel(this TagDto dto)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TagDto, Tag>()
                .ForMember(post => post.Posts, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Posts))
                .ConstructUsing(post => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Tag>(post.Posts));
            var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Tag>(dto);
            return model;
        }

        public static TagDto Tag_ToDto(this Tag model)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>()
                .ForMember(post => post.Posts, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Posts))
                .ConstructUsing(post => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TagDto>(post.Posts));
            var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TagDto>(model);
            return dto;
        }

public static Post Post_ToModel(this PostDto dto)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PostDto, Post>()
                .ForMember(prop => prop.Comments, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Comments))
                .ForMember(prop => prop.Tags, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Tags))
                .ConstructUsing(category => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Post>(category.Category))
                .ConstructUsing(tag=>AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Post>(tag.Tags));
            var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Post>(dto);
            return model;
        }

        public static PostDto Post_ToDto(this Post model)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Post, PostDto>()
                .ForMember(prop => prop.Comments, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Comments))
                .ForMember(prop => prop.Tags, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Tags)
                .ConstructUsing(category => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PostDto>(category.Category))
                .ConstructUsing(tag => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PostDto>(tag.Tags));
            var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PostDto>(model);
            return dto;
        }

public static Category Category_ToModel(this CategoryDto dto)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryDto, Category>()
                .ForMember(post => post.Posts, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Posts));
            var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Category>(dto);
            return model;
        }
        public static CategoryDto Category_ToModel(this Category model)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
                .ForMember(post => post.Posts, expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.Posts));
            var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CategoryDto>(model);
            return dto;
        }
```

I'm all out of ideas and haven't been able to find any good tutorial on how to map this kind.
I think is the fact that for example in my category , the "Post" is not mapping as it should, 
still the "Post" has some other navigation props like IdentityUser, Tag, Comment, and Category
and all those entities have navigation props as well. 
This kind of configuration is my final but i've benn trying others, the only time it worked was 
when i used the Ignore() for member, but it means that thoes props will not be mapped.
are any automapper users that had this kind of problem and are willing to help? 
thank you

Comment: Please post stacktrace of error. Also Automapper has a validator function you can run to test your mappings are correct. Make sure you correct all the warnings as well as errors.

Comment: Exception snapshot

{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nPost -> PostDto\r\nModel.Modeles.
Post -> ModelDto.DTO.PostDto\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nCategoryDto.Posts.Posts.
Posts0[0]\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nModel.Modeles.Post"}

Exception:Thrown: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping." 
(AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException) A AutoMapper.
AutoMapperMappingException was thrown: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."  sorry for the late replay, i hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should call createMap when the app starts up, from global.asax.cs or something similar. Setup all your mappings **once** before trying to do any map operations. You need to have all your mappings setup so it can map child properties, then you won't have to call ForMember for the things like Posts.

Oh and get rid of the construct Using. Just use Mapper.Map.